# Fourier Exercise (Folland 8.18)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

I would appreciate if someone could help me with the following Folland's exercise 8.18:

> Suppose $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$.
>   **a.** The $L^2$ derivative $f'$ (in the sense of Exercises 8 and 9) exists iff $\xi \widehat f\in L^2$, in which case $\widehat{f'}(\xi)=2\pi i\xi \widehat{f}(\xi)$.
>   **b.** If the $L^2$ derivative $f'$ exists then
>   $$\left[\int|f(x)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x\right]^2 \le 4 \int x|f(x)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}x \int |f'(x)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}x.$$
>   (If the integrals on the right are finite then one can integrate by parts to obtain $\int|f|^2=-2\operatorname{Re}[\int x\overline ff']$.)
>   **c. (Heisenberg inequality)** For any $b,\beta\in\mathbb R$,
>   $$\int (x-b)^2 |f(x)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}x \int (\xi-\beta)^2 |\widehat f(\xi)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}\xi \ge \frac{\|f\|^4_2}{16\pi^2}.$$

The definition of $L^{p}$ derivative:

Suppose that $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$.If there exists $h\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ such that 
$$\lim_{y\to 0}\left\Vert \frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}-h(x)\right\Vert_{p}=0,$$
we call $h$ the **(strong)**$L^{p}$ **derivative** of $f$.

In fact I can't see how to solve letter (a), since I dont know how to uses L2 derivative condition there. I also tried to solve letter (b), but applying integration by parts, I could get what he states.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.